# Stop mouse interfering with Cmd + Tab menu

Tags: application-switcher

When pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> the mouse can steal focus of a program icon. This is frustrating.

Is there a setting to make the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> ignore the mouse?

Comment: Proving negatives is difficult  ;)

Comment: It only takes focus when the cursor moves. Do you want to move your cursor while switching programs? Also, there is no setting I know of which can disable this behaviour, though there may be third party solutions.

Comment: @duci9y I only ask because I use cmd + tab all the time, and it's annoying me. As a web developer I might start to switch apps before an action has completed holding cmd until it does, then press cmd + r in a browser, during that time the mouse has moved my focus.

Comment: When the focus changes, is the cursor moving? If yes, then there is no setting you can change to disable this behaviour. If you think the cursor is not moving, there may be other problems.

Comment: @duci9y Yes the mouse is moving, I'm not reporting a bug, I'm asking if it is possible to `Stop mouse interfering with Cmd + Tab menu`. I am looking for suggestions for 3rd party plugin's or settings to change that are not in system preferences

Comment: Then no, there isn’t.

Comment: @duci9y That's quite frustrating, then. My mouse really should not be altering my workflow without a _click_. I realize that this is a long shot, especially for Apple/UI issues, but do you happen to know where one might request for Apple to make a feature that disables this interaction?

Comment: @CoreDumpError apple.com/feedback

Comment: Maybe I am missing the question?...   I have been using CMD-Tab for the last 20 years on Mac and Windows machines.   Don;t know when it became sensitive to mouse movements, but is probably years ago.   Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) provides an **Activate Application Switcher** action that you can map to <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> in a macro to replace the OS X application switcher.

Within the **Activate Application Switcher** action there is an option **Enable mouse rollover selection** that is on by default but can be disabled. This won't be a seamless replacement to the OS X application switcher but it's something to try and see if you like it.

[image: Example Keyboard Maestro macro to replace the OS X application switcher]

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problems. There is no setting I know of to disable the mouse from interfering with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, but `Mission Control` is a great alternative. You can press <kbd>F3</kbd> or click its dock icon:

[image: Exposé/Mission Control icon]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [LightSwitch X](http://sysbeep.com/). It's no longer maintained by the developer, but I'm using the last version (2.8.3, circa November 2014) under 10.12.6 and it works well.